# WPF system FontFamily location

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I have an application that allows the user to pick a `FontFamily`, `FontWeight`, `FontStyle`, and `FontStretch` combination from a picker. The picker is [WpfColorFontDialog](https://github.com/sskodje/WpfColorFont). I need the actual `TTF/FON` file from `C:\System\Fonts` based on the chosen combination.

The same application serves a very simple web application from an embedded web server.

The ultimate result is to serve the font file (ideally converted to WOFF) as part of this embedded web application.

Answer (score 0):

Among the namespace its the `FontFamily` is present is present in  `System.Windows.Media.FontFamily`, you may include it in your project and use it. However you may also create a new one by declaring it like:

```
myTextBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"), "./resources/#Pericles Light, Verdana");
```

But the best method is not to declare it dynamically from code but to include it in the xaml files.
And if you want the actual location of the installed fonts you'll get them
 `C:\Windows\Fonts or C:\WINNT\Fonts`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am afraid it doesn't solve my problem. I do not know what the font will be until run time (as it is a user selection). Once the user chooses the font family, style, and weight, I need to retrieve the actual TTF file and serve (or convert) it.